# How to setup default source interface for multicast?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, multicast

[image: network]

There is a server 172.16.0.50 with udpxy. It converts multicast video to http unicast streaming to "R2" router clients. There is igmp-proxy setup on "R1". 
My aim is remove igmp-proxy and link between "R1" and switch (the red wire on the diagram) and connect multicast source to the "SRV" directly (It may reduce cpu usage on R1) 
So, i've used this cmd to receive mcast from "R1":

```
 udpxy -a eth0 -T -p 8080 -S -c 40 -B 1Mb
```

Then i've tried to specify mcast source interface:

```
 udpxy -a eth0 -T -p 8080 -S -c 40 -B 1Mb -m eth1
```

I added route to that interface, but udpxy hadn't received anything:

```
route add -net 239.200.0.0/24 eth1
```

Please tell me, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The proper command to override it would be `ip route add multicast 239.200.0.0/24 dev eth1` (but this might only be a part of the problem).

Comment: You should capture everywhere on R1 and on SRV, on each interface, multicast control traffic (IGMP, PIM ...) to see what might be different.